# Python source code parsing: "runtime introspection parsing" versus "AST parsing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am planning on implementing an automated-documentation tool for a python project.

I have already worked on a similar projects in other programming languages and I am familiar with Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) code parsing. Python appears to have a dedicated library which correspond to my needs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

However, during my researches I found out that Python also provides some advanced introspection functionalities, giving the ability to find out information about objects at runtime ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html ). By inspecting every object of my modules, I may therefore  be able to parse my source code in a "runtime approach".

This approach seems to be considerably more accessible, as it doesn't require to generate and navigate through Abstract Syntax Trees, which by experience can get quite tedious. The objects can be inspected in a procedural way and by quickly looking at the documentation, it doesn't looks like anything is missing. Except maybe the comments who obviously doesn't count as objects and that will therefore require some workaround to be retrieved.

Since the concept is still new to me, I am likely missing some other limitations: it seems too good to be true. My question is the following: **What are the strengths and weakness of a "runtime introspection parsing" approach, does it come with limitations that the classic AST parsing approach doesn't have ?**

Note that I am not asking for an abstract debate over which approach is better, but precise facts, references, or expertise about the "runtime introspection parsing approach" limitations, strengths and weaknesses over the AST parsing approach.

Comment: `ast` does actual parsing but `"runtime introspection parsing"` (scare quotes your own) seems more of an idea waiting to be fleshed out than something which you can directly use. You seem to be asking for an objective comparison between an existing library and something which is still just an idea. In any event, if `inspect` does what you want more easily than `ast` -- just use it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not feel that introspection can replace parsing. With introspection you can find out what the python parser/compiler understood and translated it's AST into.

The difference to the normal parsing approach should be evident for syntax or grammar errors: If you parse yourself, you could detect this and give an appropriate error message. In case of introspection, you would not see anything suitable to base the error message upon - it should have been shown by the python parser anyway.